# Android send full stack trace via Crashlytics

Tags: android, logging, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have read the [Crashlytics doc](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html) and doesn't found a clue on how to send the full stack trace without make the app crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this is the solution

```
Crashlytics.logException(new Throwable());
```